# don't hide Lightbox if child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Lightbox, and inside a centered child with content. The child also has a close button. I only want to hide the Lightbox, when the Lightbox is clicked or the close button. At the moment it also gets closed, if the child is clicked.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/038pe4Ly/)

HTML

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="child">
        <a class="close" href="#"><span>x</span></a>
        <header>
            <h4>content</h4>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.lightbox, .close').on('click', function(){
    $('.lightbox').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Try `$('.lightbox *:not(header)').on('click', function() { return false; });`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with `e.target` like,

```
$('.close,.lightbox').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents(".lightbox").length && !$(e.target).is(".close,.close > span"))
    return;
    $('.lightbox').fadeOut();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/038pe4Ly/2)